# How can I build and run 32-bit software on 64-bit Debian?

Tags: debian, 64bit, x86, 32bit, development

I'm looking into developing a C++ program that needs a proprietary 32-bit library and which should run on 64-bit Debian (jessie, amd64). I assume I need to create a 32-bit executable in order to be able to use that 32-bit library (or is there a way to use that library from a 64-bit executable?)

How can I build my program on 64-bit Debian? Or should I use a 32-bit Debian machine to build it, and transfer to the 64-bit Debian afterwards?

I normally use cmake, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/q/454253/173666

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/q/1270351/173666

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/a/905083/173666

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, to use a 32-bit library you need to create a 32-bit binary.

On Debian 8 on amd64, you can build 32-bit binaries using [`gcc-multilib`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gcc-multilib) (for C) or [`g++-multilib`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/g++-multilib) (for C++) and GCC’s `-m32` option.

Using CMake, I imagine adding `-m32` to the flags would be sufficient. It is possible to set CMake up for both 32- and 64-bit builds in a single project, but it’s rather involved; see [`rr`’s `CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/mozilla/rr/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) for a detailed example.

To *run* 32-bit binaries, you’ll need to enable multi-arch support for i386:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the appropriate libraries, starting with `libc6:i386` and `libstdc++6:i386`.